# Django mutivalue field

Tags: django, django-models, model

I'm using Django 1.7 and have the following modeling problem, there are two models and one
makes reference to the other more than once as in this snippet:

```
class SchoolInfo(Model):
  name = ...
  address = ...

class PersonInfo(Model):
  elementary = OneToOneField(SchoolInfo)
  colege = OneToOneField(SchoolInfo)
```

The problem with this is that the form for `PersonInfo` shows a select field so you can pick for predefined `SchoolInfo` instances, what I want is to display `SchoolInfo` fields as they were part of `PersonInfo` like this (imagine it's a web form):

```
elementary info
school name: <text area>   address: <text area>

colege name: <text area>   address: <text area>
```

So when `PersonInfo` is saved to the database, al the `SchoolInfo` instances are saved as well.

Comment: so would you say that you would like to save *new* instances of SchoolInfo when you *create* a new PersonInfo? what if that school already exists?

Comment: @xblitz not very likely to happen, my actual models are different but the idea is the same, all must be different and be saved independently of each other.

Answer (score 1):

You need, probably, an [inline model formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet), note that you had colege instead of college

```
ElemFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    SchoolInfo, PersonInfo,
    instancefk_name="elementary",
    can_delete=False, max_num=1, min_num=1)
CollegeFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    SchoolInfo, PersonInfo,
    fk_name="college", can_delete=False, max_num=1, min_num=1)
```

using that in a viewm that can add new people info, or edit one by providing their personinfo pk in the url, (beware, untested code, could make your cat explode):

```
class PersonInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PersonInfo
        fields = ('something',) # do not put here elementary or college

def manage_personinfo(request, pid=None):
    p = PersonInfo.objects.filter(pk=pid)
    instance = p[0] if p.exists() else None
    pf_form = PersonInfoForm(request.POST or None,
                             request.FILES or None,
                             instance=instance)

    ElemFormset = inlineformset_factory(
        SchoolInfo, PersonInfo,
        instancefk_name="elementary",
        can_delete=False, max_num=1, min_num=1)
    CollegeFormset = inlineformset_factory(
        SchoolInfo, PersonInfo,
        fk_name="college", can_delete=False, max_num=1, min_num=1)

    e_formset = ElemFormset(
        request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,
        instance=instance, prefix="elementary")
    c_formset = SchoolFormset(
        request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,
        instance=instance, prefix="college")

    if pf_form.is_valid() and e_formset.is_valid() and c_formset.is_valid():
        e_formset.save()
        c_formset.save()
        instance = pf_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    return render_to_response("manage_personinfo.html", {
        "e_form": e_formset,
        "c_formset": c_formset,
        "pf_formset": pf_formset,
    })
```

and the url being something like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^editpinfo/(?<pid>\d+)/$', manage_personinfo),
)
```